# Oracle german character are converted to junk character?

Tags: windows, oracle, character-encoding, sqlplus

I have created simple table which has only one field `TCHAR`

```
SQL> desc test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------

 TCHAR                                              CHAR(20)
```

I have created one .sql file and run the sql script from `sqlplus` using 
`@filepath..\germantest.sql` then output was getting replaced with some junk words

Output:

```
SQL> select * from test;

TCHAR
--------------------
├ä
Wir best├ƒ
Nauch ├á ├ó ├¥
```

But when I try to insert same data run directly on sqlplus instead of file then

Input

```
insert into test values('Ärger Ökonom');
insert into test values('Ä');
insert into test values('Wir bestß');
insert into test values('Nauch à â Ý');
```

Output

```
SQL> select * from test;

TCHAR
--------------------
Ärger Ökonom
Ä
Wir bestß
Nauch à â Y
```

The output shows here is correct.

What I tried till now.

1. I checked file format and it must be utf-8
2. I checked NLS_charset and it is AL32UTF8.

What did I expect?

3. When I run same file from sqldeveloper, then I am getting correct output.

I want to run same script from .sql file and want to retain german characters in database as it is in original file.

Comment: If those characters are displayed correctly in SQL Developer they are _stored_ correctly in the database. The fact that SQL\*Plus doesn't diplay them correctly means your console font doesn't support those characters (or UTF-8). Another option is that the NLS environment for SQL\*Plus is incorrectly configured. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: we are using the windows7. data is not correctly stored when we run file from sqldeveloper we are getting correct output but when we run same file  from sqlplus getting weird output.

Comment: Check your NLS configuration in Windows for SQL\*Plus. It is most probably not using UTF-8. The environment variable `NLS_LANG` needs to be set correctly

Comment: what is the correct value of NLS_LANG? I have currently try this one set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

Comment: Which codepage do you use in the windows console?

Comment: See e.g. here: http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-13434.html

Comment: active code page was 437

Comment: Then you probably need something like `set NLS_LANG=.WE8PC437`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134749/discussion-between-maheshwar-ligade-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codepage in the Windows console **must** match the `NLS_LANG` setting for SQL*Plus.

In a nutshell you need:

```
c:\> chcp 65001
c:\> SET NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.AL32UTF8
```

You can easily verify if your code page is correct if you run `type germantest.sql` in the console. If that doesn't display the file contents correctly you have the wrong codepage:

[image]

Now the codepage **has** to match the NLS_LANG setting:

[image]

The correct value for NLS_LANG is also important when running a SQL script because it determines the encoding in which the file is read by SQL*Plus.

Of course `cmd.exe` needs to be configured to use a font that can actually display those characters.

Comment: This is not working when I set chcp 65001 and try to run sql query database is automatically looged out. When try to run .sql file then it throws exception SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ï»¿insert in..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> select * from test;

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade: sounds as if your SQL script is stored using an [UTF8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) I don't think SQL\*Plus supports that

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade: of course not, that's a Windows command. You stated you are using Windows 7.

Comment: I used on windows7 its work fine I want for unix now.